# How to have non-system fonts in SVG render properly?

Tags: svg, fonts

I have an SVG embedded via an `img` with the following defs. The `Providence Pro` font is installed and is rendering fine in a variety of other places in the app but not in the SVG unless it is added to the computer's system fonts (e.g. via FontBook or TypeKit)

```
<defs>
  <style>
    .cls-1 {
      stroke:#000;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
    }
    .cls-2 {
      fill:#fff;
    }
    .cls-3 {
      font-size:38.03px;
      font-family:ProvidencePro, Providence Pro;
    }
  </style>
</defs>
```

Is it possible to have SVGs render text internally with a custom font and if so how?